# $A_f \otimes_A A_g = A_{fg} $

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, localization

A is a commutative  ring. $f,g\in A$. Then I want to show  $A_f \otimes_A A_g = A_{fg}$.
I tried proving it by constructing a bilinear form from $A_f \times A_g$ to $A_{fg}$. But I could not figure out how the bilinear form would look like. Is there any other way to do this problem?

Comment: Hint: do you see why $(A_f)_g=A_{fg}$?

Comment: Yes I can see that.

Comment: Should I take the bilinear form from A_f x A_g to (A_f)_g  where ( a/f^n, b/g^m) goes to (ab/f^n g^m) ?

Comment: This should work, but it's also true more generally that $M\otimes_A A_g=M_g$.